# cucumber.json file does not generating

Tags: maven, cucumber

I am trying to execute a cucumber selenium setup.

pom.xml is like.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>ExecuteAutomation</projectName>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and cucumber jvm is

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**whenever I verify the build by maven it always shows cucumber.json does not exist.
which suppose to be auto generated.**

runner file is

```
@CucumberOptions(features = { "src/test/features/Login.feature" },monochrome = false,
    plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.json","html:target/site/cucumber-pretty"},
    glue = { "steps" })
```

Comment: Your feature file is being executed?

Comment: Through TestNG --yes, Through maven -- no

Comment: Refer [GitHub PM](https://github.com/DilipMeghwal/BDD_Selenium_TestNG_Maven_CucumberReporting/blob/master/pom.xml) as a reference and add maven-surefire-plugin to run the testng file.

Comment: already added v 2.21.0

Comment: update surefire-plugin v to 3.0.0-M2 also not worked

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I back track the problem
first I comment maven-cucumber-reporting plugin section and try to execute through testng. there was a warning which need to resolve by -Dtestng.dtd.http=true.

and then it works!

Thanks!